# How to change the value of a <text> from a different screen?

Tags: react-native

This might be a dumb question, as Im really new react native and Im not really sure if Im doing things right.

Basically I have 2 screens, home and setMoney.

in home, i have a `<text>${this.state.money}</text>` that I get from AsyncStorage.getItem(). setMoney is where I do the setItem. It works fine and I can see whatever I put on the setMoney screen at home, but I have to reload first. If I just switch between screens, it doesnt show the changes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked out any state management libraries like redux or mobx?

Comment: @Perniferous I havent yet, I just started just a couple of hours ago, and wasnt aware. I assumed it was something supported natively. But I will go ahead and read about it.

Comment: It is supported natively in React through leveraging props between screens. If you are looking to do change a lot of state globally, a state management library could help you a lot in the long run.

Comment: @Perniferous I would like to know how this is done, just so I know how it works.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I misunderstood that there is two parts to your question, you are also leveraging an async call which would only populate the data when you are currently on that screen. I believe what you wanna do is be able to call that function as well from a different screen and see the data change on the previous screen?

Comment: @Perniferous yes, but I can seem to make it work no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to implement redux in your application and put money in global state of the app, it will need no reloading and money will get get updated as soon as you change it. A work around would be to use [react-native-event-listners](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-event-listeners) as in below example

In your home screen's **componentDidMount** function

```
EventRegister. addEventListener('updated',()=>{
AsyncStorage.getItem()
.then(item=>{
this.setState({money:item})
})
})
```

In your set money screen inside the function after you have set the item in storage you can do

```
EventRegister.emit('updated')
```

You can also send value of money directly without using storage by the same package by doing this:

In your home screen's **componentDidMount** function

```
EventRegister. addEventListener('updated',(item)=>{

this.setState({money:item})

})
```

In your set money screen inside the function after you have set the item in storage you can do

```
EventRegister.emit('updated',valueToSend)
```

Comment: Thanks. One of the hardest parts of learning a new language is not being familiar with what's available.